# Mongoose creating multiple documents instead of one

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am learning web development and have a little project where I am creating a todolist. I am using Javascript, Node.js and Mongoose.

**PROBLEM**
When routing to a different page (i.e. a new list), if the list doesn't exist, a new document is to be created in my database with its name. If it does exist, then the page should just render without creating another document.

However, when calling a new page, Mongoose creates MULTIPLE documents of the same name (but different IDs). If I try to call a new different page, Mongoose creates one new document, as expected.

My code is -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Connect to mongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/toDoListDB',  {useNewUrlParser : true});

// Set up port
const port = 3000;


//--------  Set-up Mongoose Schemas and Models ------------

// Homepage list schema - takes in todo list item
const itemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
  listEntry: String
});

const Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemsSchema);

// New page/list schema - takes listtname and list items array
const listsSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
  customListName: String,
  lists: [itemsSchema]
});

const List = mongoose.model('List', listsSchema);


// Default array with how to use list
const defaultEntriesArray = ['Welcome...', 'Hit the +...', '<-- Hit this...'];


// --------------- Render pages for User custom Lists  ------------

// Direct to a user defined list
app.get('/:newListName', function (req, res) {

  // Get list litle
  const listNameTitle = req.params.newListName;

  // Check if the list already exists
  List.findOne({customListName: listNameTitle}, function(err, existingList){

    if (!err){

      //Check if list exists already
        if(existingList === null){

         // Create a new list
         const list = new List({
           customListName: listNameTitle,
           lists: defaultEntriesArray
         });

         // Save list and redirect to current page
         list.save();
         res.redirect('/' + listNameTitle);

        // if list already exists - listTitle & newListItems are passed to HTML/EJS file
        }else{
          console.log('exists');
          res.render('list', {listTitle:existingList.customListName, newListItems: existingList.lists} )
       }
    }
  });
});
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**
Starting with an empty database, when a user searches for localhost3000/work, a new Mongoose document should be created called 'work'. Instead I get three -

```
> db.lists.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a3519298544dbad1a043"), "customListName" : "work", "lists" : [ { "listEntry" : "Welcome to your ToDoList!", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbc") }, { "listEntry" : "Hit the + buton to add a new item.", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbd") }, { "listEntry" : "<-- Hit this to delete an item.", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbe") } ], "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a3519298544dbad1a07f"), "customListName" : "work", "lists" : [ { "listEntry" : "Welcome to your ToDoList!", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbc") }, { "listEntry" : "Hit the + buton to add a new item.", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbd") }, { "listEntry" : "<-- Hit this to delete an item.", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbe") } ], "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a3519298544dbad1a055"), "customListName" : "work", "lists" : [ { "listEntry" : "Welcome to your ToDoList!", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbc") }, { "listEntry" : "Hit the + buton to add a new item.", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbd") }, { "listEntry" : "<-- Hit this to delete an item.", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbe") } ], "__v" : 0 }
```

This does not happen if I continue generating new pages. Adding another page/list called shopping, only generates one document - as expected - (plus the initial three 'Work') -

```
> db.lists.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a3519298544dbad1a043"), "customListName" : "work", "lists" : [ { "listEntry" : "Welcome to your ToDoList!", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbc") }, { "listEntry" : "Hit the + buton to add a new item.", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbd") }, { "listEntry" : "<-- Hit this to delete an item.", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbe") } ], "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a3519298544dbad1a07f"), "customListName" : "work", "lists" : [ { "listEntry" : "Welcome to your ToDoList!", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbc") }, { "listEntry" : "Hit the + buton to add a new item.", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbd") }, { "listEntry" : "<-- Hit this to delete an item.", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbe") } ], "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a3519298544dbad1a055"), "customListName" : "work", "lists" : [ { "listEntry" : "Welcome to your ToDoList!", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbc") }, { "listEntry" : "Hit the + buton to add a new item.", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbd") }, { "listEntry" : "<-- Hit this to delete an item.", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbe") } ], "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a3c29298544dbad1a089"), "customListName" : "shopping", "lists" : [ { "listEntry" : "Welcome to your ToDoList!", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbc") }, { "listEntry" : "Hit the + buton to add a new item.", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbd") }, { "listEntry" : "<-- Hit this to delete an item.", "_id" : ObjectId("61f1a2ed9298544dbad19fbe") } ], "__v" : 0 }
```

Rerouting to JUST the home page with `res.redirect('/');` seems to solve the problem (only one document of 'work' is created) , but I do not want this. I need it to redirect to the new page.
Why is Mongoose generating multiple documents in the first instance of being called?

Comment: Just want to mention that it's a bad practice to create/update state of the entities inside HTTP GET method handler. Get is for getting data, not creating it. Use post instead.

Comment: I would suggest start debugging it to investigate the flow
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Comment: Moreover you don't await for list save() which returns promise. The behaviour will not be stable. Or in your case of callbacks you have to return response in the callback of save

Comment: .save() is async so u need to `await list.save()`. This means it will wait for mongodb to confirm the write, before u return a respond to user.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this error about not using `async/await`. Try something like that:

```js
app.get('/:newListName', async function (req, res) {

    // Get list litle
    const listNameTitle = req.params.newListName;

    // Check if the list already exists
    var existingList = await List.findOne({ customListName: listNameTitle }).catch(err => { });

    if (!existingList) {
        // Create a new list
        const list = new List({
            customListName: listNameTitle,
            lists: defaultEntriesArray
        });

        // Save list and redirect to current page
        await list.save();
        res.redirect('/' + listNameTitle);

        // if list already exists - listTitle & newListItems are passed to HTML/EJS file
    } else {
        console.log('exists');
        res.render('list', { listTitle: existingList.customListName, newListItems: existingList.lists })
    }
});
```